# Insert table data from website into table on my own website using Python and Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I wrote some code that grabs the numbers I need from [this website](http://abri.une.edu.au/online/cgi-bin/i4.dll?1=2021292A&2=2420&3=56&5=2B3C2B3C3A&6=59585A242621582623&9=5251595A), but I don't know what to do next.

It grabs the numbers from the table at the bottom. The ones under calving ease, birth weight, weaning weight, yearling weight, milk and total maternal.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pyperclip

def getPageData(url):

    if not ('abri.une.edu.au' in url):
        return -1
    webpage = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage, "html.parser")

    # This finds the epd tree and saves it as a searchable list
    pedTreeTable = soup.find('table', {'class':'TablesEBVBox'})

    # This puts all of the epds into a list.
    # it looks for anything in pedTreeTable with an td tag.
    pageData = pedTreeTable.findAll('td')
    pageData.pop(7)
    return pageData

def createPedigree(animalPageData):
    ''' make animalPageData much more useful. Strip the text out and put it in a dict.''' 
    animals = []
    for animal in animalPageData:
        animals.append(animal.text)

    prettyPedigree = {
    'calving_ease' : animals[18],
    'birth_weight' : animals[19],
    'wean_weight' : animals[20],
    'year_weight' : animals[21],
    'milk' : animals[22],
    'total_mat' : animals[23]
    }    

    for animalKey in prettyPedigree:
        if animalKey != 'year_weight' and animalKey != 'dam':
            prettyPedigree[animalKey] = stripRegNumber(prettyPedigree[animalKey])
    return prettyPedigree

def stripRegNumber(animal):
    '''returns the animal with its registration number stripped'''
    lAnimal = animal.split()
    strippedAnimal = ""
    for word in lAnimal:
        if not word.isdigit():
            strippedAnimal += word + " "
    return strippedAnimal

def prettify(pedigree):
    ''' Takes the pedigree and prints it out in a usable format  '''
    s = ''

    pedString = ""

    # this is also ugly, but it was the only way I found to format with a variable
    cFormat = '{{:^{}}}'
    rFormat = '{{:>{}}}'

    #row 1 of string
    s += rFormat.format(len(pedigree['calving_ease'])).format(
                            pedigree['calving_ease']) + '\n'

    #row 2 of string
    s += rFormat.format(len(pedigree['birth_weight'])).format(
                            pedigree['birth_weight']) + '\n'

    #row 3 of string
    s += rFormat.format(len(pedigree['wean_weight'])).format(
                            pedigree['wean_weight']) + '\n'

    #row 4 of string
    s += rFormat.format(len(pedigree['year_weight'])).format(
                            pedigree['year_weight']) + '\n'

    #row 4 of string
    s += rFormat.format(len(pedigree['milk'])).format(
                            pedigree['milk']) + '\n'

    #row 5 of string
    s += rFormat.format(len(pedigree['total_mat'])).format(
                            pedigree['total_mat']) + '\n'


    return s

if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        url = raw_input('Input a url you want to use to make life easier: \n')
        pageData = getPageData(url)
        s = prettify(createPedigree(pageData))
        pyperclip.copy(s)
        if len(s) > 0:
            print 'the easy string has been copied to your clipboard'
```

I've just been using this code for easy copying and pasting. All I have to do is insert the URL, and it saves the numbers to my clipboard.

Now I want to use this code on my website; I want to be able to insert a URL in my HTML code, and it displays these numbers on my page in a table.

My questions are as follows:

1. How do I use the python code on the website?
2. How do I insert collected data into a table with HTML?

Comment: What framework are you using on your site?

Comment: I was hoping to implement this on multiple websites. Also I don't entirely understand the different types of frameworks. I'm very amateur and so are my websites. I don't know if this info helps but I use html, css, and javascript

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you would want to use something like [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com). Although the learning curve is a bit steep, it is worth it *and* it (of course) supports python.